# Can i change the formatting of specific words In my docx file with officer package in R?

Tags: r, officer

I'm trying to change some specific words formatting to bold but can't find the the way to do it.

For example:

I would like to change the word "text" to bold in this code:

```
doc <- read_docx() %>%
   body_add_par("This is a sample text", style = "centered")
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `body_add_fpar` to achieve that. From the documentation:

```
bold_face <- shortcuts$fp_bold(font.size = 30)
bold_redface <- update(bold_face, color = "red")
fpar_ <- fpar(ftext("Hello ", prop = bold_face),
              ftext("World", prop = bold_redface ),
              ftext(", how are you?", prop = bold_face ) )
doc <- read_docx() %>% body_add_fpar(fpar_)
```